# How come difftime() gives me answers way out of proportion?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have date time values and I'd like to calculate the difference. I tried to use `-` between the two times, as in `t1 - t2` but it switches the units. Some of the output is in minutes, some in hours and some in days- which makes it hard to work with.

I used difftime from lubridate and it gave me results that don't make sense.

```
my_tibble %>%
    mutate(time_diff = difftime(t2, t1, units = "mins")) 

   t1                       t2           time_diff           
   <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>          
 1 2018-06-30 18:26:28 2018-07-01 01:26:43   0.2342667 mins
 2 2018-06-30 19:33:03 2018-07-01 09:36:56 423.8818500 mins
 3 2018-06-30 19:32:51 2018-07-01 02:33:41   0.8219833 mins
 4 2018-06-30 23:09:59 2018-07-01 06:11:45   1.7654167 mins
 5 2018-06-30 23:22:30 2018-07-01 06:23:00   0.4852000 mins
```

Here's more information.

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   6 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ t1: POSIXct, format: "2018-07-01 01:26:43" "2018-07-01 09:36:56" "2018-07-01 02:33:41" "2018-07-01 06:11:45"
```

For what it's worth, the file comes from a CSV that has the time `t1` defined as the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch. Here is how I read in the dataframe.

```
my_tibble <- read_csv("table.csv") %>% 
  mutate(t1 = as.POSIXct(epoch_milli / 1000, origin="1970-01-01")) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, as.character) %>% 
        as_tibble()
```

Comment: Cauder, if this is your code, then there is no way you could have produced that output (missing quote). If it is not your code, then please correct it.  Either way, combine that with "no sample data provided" and your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: This is the output I get. I unloaded all my packages, except tidyverse.

Comment: Thank you for fixing your code, glad to hear that wasn't the issue. You said *"some in hours and some in days"*, but your sample data here shows only minutes. I cannot reproduce your "mins/days" problem, and I don't understand what does not make sense about this output. Perhaps you could clearly show what you expect the output to be?

Comment: I'd like the output to be the proper number of minutes.

Comment: That's apparent, but what should they be? We don't have time zone for anything, so I'm guessing that your `t2` field is a different zone (no idea how you get or make that field). Realize that your sample frame in the question is ambiguous: it doesn't show millis or tz. Can you either (1) provide the output from `dput(head(my_tibble))`, or (2) give us samples from `table.csv` plus code to generate `t2`?

Comment: As a demonstration of what I suspect, `difftime(as.POSIXct("2018-07-01 01:26:42.5", tz="UTC"), as.POSIXct("2018-06-30 18:26:28.49", tz="US/Pacific"), units="mins")` shows `0.2335 mins`. In this case, it's clear that the two time zones completely offset the 420 minutes you would expect by looking just at the dates/hours. You can (dis)prove this with `attr(my_tibble$t2, "tzone")` (and same for `$t1`), where an empty string `""` means the zone local to the computer on which R is running (ref: [`?strptime`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/strptime)).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't be able to reproduce the issue after quoting the `"mins` correctly (`"mins"`).  Also, `difftime` is a `base R` function

```
library(dplyr)
my_tibble %>%
     mutate(time_diff = difftime(t2, t1, units = "mins")) 
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  t1                  t2                  time_diff    
#  <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>       
#1 2018-06-30 18:26:28 2018-07-01 01:26:43 420.2500 mins
#2 2018-06-30 19:33:03 2018-07-01 09:36:56 843.8833 mins
#3 2018-06-30 19:32:51 2018-07-01 02:33:41 420.8333 mins
#4 2018-06-30 23:09:59 2018-07-01 06:11:45 421.7667 mins
#5 2018-06-30 23:22:30 2018-07-01 06:23:00 420.5000 mins
```

#### data

```
my_tibble <- structure(list(t1 = structure(c(1530383188, 1530387183, 1530387171, 
1530400199, 1530400950), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    t2 = structure(c(1530408403, 1530437816, 1530412421, 1530425505, 
    1530426180), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), 
     row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```